# Character Repeater Function

Tags: python, function, loops, character, repeat

I need to create a function in Python to iterate over a given string, in this case 'hello-world' and have an output where characters in the string that do not have pairs, are printed with a paired character.

Input String: hello-world

Output String: hheello--wworrldd

So for this example, I only want to repeat the characters 'h' 'e' 'w' 'r' 'd' and not repeat 'l' or 'o'
I tried this function, and it did repeat the characters, but I am not sure how to isolate only the characters that do not have a pair in the string.

```
def character_pair(n, input_string):
    word = ''
    for char in list(input_string):
        word += char * n
    print (word)

character_pair(2, 'hello-world')
```

This was my output:
hheelllloo--wwoorrlldd

Comment: You don't need `list(input_string)`. `for char in input_string:` works.

Comment: Okay, thank you for helping me clean that part of the code up! My problem is that I don't want to repeat every character in the string, only the ones that don't have another letter in the string. So in this example: 'h' 'e' 'w' 'r' 'd' should be repeated, but 'l', 'o' should not.

Comment: Yes, that's clear in the question.

Comment: The `l` in world isn't repeated because it's paired in `hello`?

Comment: Oh, it's not just adjacent pairs, it doesn't double `o` because it's in both `hello` and `world`.

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: So first go through the string finding all the characters that appear just once. Then go through it again, multiplying anything that isn't in that set.

Comment: You can do the first part using `collections.Counter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter` to count the repetitions of each character. Then check if the count is 1 before multiplying the character.

```
import collections

def character_pair(n, input_string):
    counts = collections.Counter(input_string)
    word = ''
    for char in input_string:
        if counts[char] > 1:
            word += char
        else:
            word += char * n
    print (word)

character_pair(2, 'hello-world')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'hello-world'
new_word = ''

for each_char in string:
    if string.count(each_char) > 1:
        new_word += each_char
    else:
        new_word += each_char * 2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeatChar(n, sentence): 
    words = ''
    for char in list(sentence):
        word += char * n
    print(words)


sentence = input('Here you can write.. ')
repeatChar(2, sentence)
```